# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I ran into a very vague error while doing some simple jQuery DOM manipulation.

The line that triggered the error is the following:

`$(this).closest('tr').remove();`

The error, as stated in the title, is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

in file: `jquery-1.6.2.js`.

I have already tried with jQuery 1.6.3 and jQuery 1.5.1, but nothing changed. I still keep getting the error.

The line above is bound to a button which, when clicked, submits an AJAX POST request, then when successful, it removes its own `<tr>`. I have already tried another way by doing:

`$(this).parent().parent().remove()` but to my surprise, this did nothing.

I'm using Chrome, in case it matters, but I get the same error in FF.

EDIT:

This is my code:

```
$(".remove").live('click', function(e)  {
    var str = $(this).attr('id').match(/\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/);
    var type = str[1];
    var id = str[2];

            // IF I PUT THE remove() HERE, IT WORKS.

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/ajax_remove_event_detail',
        data: {type: type, id: id},
        success:function(res)   {
            if(res)
            {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                // this gives me an error
            }
            else
            {
              // error handling 
            }
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If I put the remove() outside of the if somewhere, it works. Why won't it work when it's inside the ajax call/if? Makes no sense to me? :(

Any help here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you redefining `undefined` or `toLowerCase` somewhere?

Comment: What other libraries are you using? This could be a `$` conflict issue...

Comment: Daniel: no, no redefining. 

El Ronnoco: Only other library I'm using is jQuery UI; no others.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LztrJ/ works, but it's only like a minor, minor, part of my code since I have no clue how to simulate ajax requests in jsfiddle.

Comment: This is working perfectly fine in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvMdL/ .

So it must be linked to something else than just jQuery.

Comment: I just tried putting the remove() line outside of my ajax request, and there it works. Inside the request/if, it gives an error.. I updated my post with the code.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't know what you *expect* the value of `this` to be in your "success" handler, but I bet it's not what you think.  Save `this` outside the "$.ajax()" call:

```
var clicked = this;
$.ajax(
  // ...
  success: function(res) {
    if (res) {
      $(clicked).closest('tr').remove();
    }
    else {
      // ...
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Inside your request, $(this) is not the `.remove` element. It's a closure problem.

So you can assign $(this) to a variable before and call it after

Comment: Oh closures... How do I not get thee.  Let me count the ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
// assign this to a variable

var val = this;

// Use

$(val).closest('tr').remove(); // It worked for me
```

Instead of :

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

I got exactly the same error on **$.get() request**.

For me this is the most weird bug in jQuery (my version 1.8.3).

My reason for this error was **TD element with ID set to "nodeName"**.

After change ID value to something else, the error dissapear.

Original:

```
<td id="nodeName"></td>
```

New:

```
<td id="nodeNameValue"></td>
```