# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined (Youtube API)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, undefined

I found this one among others when I searched the problem : [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334481/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-tolowercase-of-undefined)
I looked it over but it did not seem relevant in my case (I might be wrong!).

Anyhow, I am using the Youtube Iframe API by including "http://www.youtube.com/player_api" in my HTML file.
When my page is ready I add 7 iframes to my DOM, they get their own id (example id="0") which I change with a for-loop, and for each iframe I call a method that applies the Youtube API functionality on the video:

```
function addPlayerAPIToVideo(vidId, link, plId) {
    if (players[plId] === undefined) {
        players[plId] = new Array();
    }

    playlistPlayers[plId][vidId] = new YT.Player(vidId, { //Error comes from the YT.Player function
        videoId: link,
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

vidId is the id on the iframe that I create before calling this method.
plId is == 0 during this error, and that value does not impact the result (in this case).
link is the Youtube video identifier, its 11 characters long and can look like this: TMTpeDM7GN0.

I might add that I can call this function one time without receiving any errors, but the second time I call it i get the error (see title). Also, Firefox tells me that the problem is "`TypeError: c.tagName is undefined`" at row 18 in "http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflZPZFPk.js".

This became fairly long, but I tried to be as thorough as possible.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hit a very similar error.  My problem appeared to be that I was passing in a JQuery element rather than a raw element, and it didn't have a tagName.  Your question gave me the clue I needed so thanks very much!  Perhaps you could try getting the element yourself rather than passing in an id, and making sure you get an object that has a tagName member.

Comment: Thanks, a year and a half later I hit the same problem again, your answer helped me solve it!