# After calling a jquery function, server side function doesn't trigger

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a Datalist with three columns or fields:

Column1:  Some data

Column2: Linkbutton Update

Column3: div "divCheck", by default it's hide.

```
<asp:DataList ID="MyDataList" runat="server" EnableViewState="True">
      <HeaderTemplate>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <table width="100%">
              <tr id="ItemRow" runat="server">
                  <td >
                      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "some_data")%>
                  </td>
                  <td >
                      <asp:LinkButton Text="Update" class="lnk_showCheck" CommandName="update" Runat="server" ID="update"   />
                  </td>
                  <td >
                      <div id="check" style="display: none">Check</div>

                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

when linkbutton is clicked, it calls a jquery function for showing a div.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('a.lnk_showCheck').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('div',$(this).closest("td").next()).show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

However, after jquery is called, this server side function is not triggered:

```
Protected Sub MyDataList_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles MyDataList.ItemCommand

        If e.CommandName = "update" Then
            ' Put some code here
            ' It doesn't trigger after LinkButton calls jquery function.

        End If

    End Sub
```

Why? How should I call this server side function?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to call jquery function ShowCheck from server side, but I don't know how to make it work like ('a.lnk_showCheck').click(function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {

            $('a.lnk_showCheck').click(function (e) {
                //e.preventDefault();
                $('div', $(this).closest("td").next()).show();            

            });

        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            function ShowCheck() {
                $('div', $(this).closest("td").next()).show();
            };

    </script>
```

Server side function calling jquery function:

```
Protected Sub MyDataList_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles MyDataList.ItemCommand

        If e.CommandName = "update" Then

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "show", " ShowCheck();", True)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Get error when calling ShowCheck jquery function.
Error: Can not get property 'toLowerCase' because it is undefined.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will stop the default action from happening....In this case, posting back to run your event handler.

Comment: Yes, but if I don't put `code`e.preventDefault();`code`, then it goes postback and div doesnt show.

Comment: In order to get to the server, you have to postback.  Its the only way that the event handler will run.  Probably your answer is that you need to test for postback and handle your div server side.

Comment: I'm trying other angle: Calling jquery function after server side function is done. However, I don't know how to construct jquery function properly.

Comment: Additionally, you could load the javascript you want to call *in* the event handler and have it run after the page has been posted back.  Using something like [RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334481/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-tolowercase-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Your RegisterStartupScript parameters are off.  You need to specify the script as Javascript.

Here is a bit of code that I use to load, call then unload a javascript function.

```
var script = string.Format(@"<script language='javascript'>
                                function f(){
                                              {
                                                 {0}(); 
                                                 Sys.Application.remove_load(f);
                                             }}; 
                                 Sys.Application.add_load(f);
                            </script>", function);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), function, script, false);
```

In your case you can replace the variable `function` with `"ShowCheck"` (no parens as they are in the string already.)

I should also note that this is in C# not VB.  It should be easy enough to translate however.

If that mess is too confusing and you just want to call your method try:

```
var script = @"<script language='javascript'> ShowCheck();</script>";

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ShowCheck", script, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I think it's other thing. When I run code, error is still there. I'm not sure if my jquery function ShowCheck is correctly written and could behave similar as `$('a.lnk_showCheck').click(function (e) {`.

Comment: @CarlosHeredia, ok.. now you've lost me.  I see in your *new* edit, that your error is `toLowerCase is undefined`.  But no where in your post are you calling `toLowerCase`.  So you clearly have not given enough information, very frustrating.

Comment: I checked that `$(this).closest("td")` gives me error `toLowerCase is undefined`. However, in `$('a.lnk_showCheck').click(function (e) {` there is no error. That's why I think that it's something wrong in function `ShowCheck`. I appreciate your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334481/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-tolowercase-of-undefined

Comment: @CarlosHeredia did you find your answer?